# PHP Fail to upload image

Tags: php

**test.php** file

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE)
        {
            echo "Please select an image";
        }
        else
        {
            $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $image = file_get_contents($image);
            $image = base64_encode($image);
            saveimage($image);
        }
    }

    function saveimage($image)
    {
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

        mysql_select_db("food",$con);

        $query = "INSERT INTO info(image) VALUES ('$image')";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$con);

        if($result)
        {
            echo "<br> Image upload";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<br> NOT";
        }
    }

function displayimage()
    {
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

        mysql_select_db("food",$con);

        $query = "SELECT image from info";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row["image"].'" width="200" height="200"/>';
    }



?>
```

**html** file

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">

    <label>Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image"><br>

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit"  value="Confirm" style="height:50px; width:100px;">

    <br><br>

</form>
```

Now i want to display the picture. But i keep getting a blank picture instead. Is there any problem with my display code there? Thanks

/dummy//aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa//dummy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data in form tag.

Answer (score 5):

Your are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `form` tag.

The **enctype** attribute specifies how the form data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

**Note:** The `enctype` attribute can be used only with `method="post"`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag.

Answer (score 0):

you make a POST request, you have to encode the data that forms the body of the request.

When writing client-side code,you need to use **multipart/form-data** if your form includes any  elements.